# How to do get text of read only text from Selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Application has a `text filed` which displays dynamically changes, after getting value of the weight of a product,that is read only, I am not able to read the values from it. Here is the code:

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement(getLocator("Weight1Value"));
System.out.println(input.getAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: why are you not able to read value??? is there any exception???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try JavascriptExecutor if the above is not working

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String Text = (String) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].value;",driver.findElement(getLocator("Weight1Value")));
```

Comment: there is no error while running that code, but its not getting the text value.

Comment: Can you tell me what is wrong in the Answer why it is downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

@Arun, just made small change & **it's working fine for me**

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String Text = (String) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].value;",driver.findElement(getLocator("Weight1Value")));
System.out.println(Text);
```

- I had made mistake in getting the `xpath` as well.

all fixed now, thanks guys

Comment: If your `xpath` is correct now, then why are you going to get value by using `JavaScript` while you could simply find value by using `driver.findElement(getLocator("Weight1Value").getAttribute("value")`

Comment: Instead of posting another answer based on Arun's answer, ask Arun to correct his code. Now we have an accepted answer that isn't correct which means that others will use it and have the same issue.